# gtts.tts.gTTSError: Failed to connect (host='translate.google.com', port=443 'Cannot connect to proxy.)

Tags: python, gtts

I am using Python (version 3.9) and GTTS (version 2.2.2) with the app.py file

```
from gtts import gTTS
tts = gTTS('hello', 'en')
tts.save('hello.mp3')
```

But When I run python app.py, the error happens. I got an error

```
 ProxyError(e, request=request)
 requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='translate.google.com', port=443): Max 
 retries exceeded with url: /_/TranslateWebserverUi/data/batchexecute (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot 
 connect to proxy.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'The existing connection was forcibly closed to the 
 remote host。', 
 None, 10054, None)))
```

I included the error pictured below.

[image]

Please help me fix it. Thank you so much.

Comment: Your proxy setup is faulty, the proxy is not working or you are having some kind of connection issues.

Comment: @KlausD. I don't know why. I can access translate.google.com on my browser. But when running my code, It did not work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply environmental proxy setting like below code before calling gTTS :

```
import os
proxy = 'http://<user>:<pass>@<proxy>:<port>'
os.environ['http_proxy'] = proxy 
os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = proxy
os.environ['https_proxy'] = proxy
os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = proxy
```